# User friendly URLs without htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create friendly urls for my website script only using PHP, right now im using the query style (Ex: index.php?location=register) and i would like to convert them to something like this:

```
https://www.sitename.com/index.php/Register
```

Right now im using a $_GET based function to parse and include the php script based on the $_GET value.

```
 $includeDir = ".".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."assets/controllers".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  $includeDefault = $includeDir."Home.php"; 
    if(isset($_GET['ajaxpage']) && !empty($_GET['ajaxpage'])){
        $_GET['ajaxpage'] = str_replace("\0", '', $_GET['ajaxpage']);
        $includeFile = basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['ajaxpage'].".php"));
        $includePath = $includeDir.$includeFile;
        if(!empty($includeFile) && file_exists($includePath)) {
            include($includePath);
        }
        else{
            include($includeDefault);
        }
        exit();
    } 

  if(isset($_GET['location']) && !empty($_GET['location']))
            {
                $_GET['location'] = str_replace("\0", '', $_GET['location']);
          $includeFile=basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['location'].".php"));
                $includePath = $includeDir.$includeFile;

                if(!empty($includeFile) && file_exists($includePath)) 
                {
                    include($includePath);
                }
                else 
                {
                    include($includeDefault);
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                include($includeDefault);
            }
```

Kind regards!

Comment: Have a look at `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: I've looked into it but i'd like to see a implementation example to understand the code.

Comment: For the path: `/index.php/Register` to work without the server returning a 404 error, this is still dependent on the server configuration (e.g. Apache's MultiView) ... and what you're doing is WAY more work than doing URL rewriting with a router that routes to a controller in just about any framework in existence.

Comment: you can use the route and through that i think you can only achieve it.

Comment: what is your real link without .htaccess code?

Comment: site.com/index.php?location=register for example. This query its based on the code in my post. Im just including the script in index.php based on the $_GET value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to show index.php in the URL?

I would create my URL to look like this `https://www.sitename.com/register` if you truly want clean URL's but you would need to use something like the rewrite.

But you would need to use `.htaccess` or `Apache config` rules such as this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?location=$1 [L]
```

Then in your PHP code you can do a get on location var `$_GET["location"]` and then load the page from the value sent.

The result of `$_GET["location"]` would be `register` from this URL and then you will display that page.

I don't suggest using MultiViews as it can cause issues if you have file and folders with the same name. e.g. `/admin and admin.php`.

Comment: I think he doesn't like to use .htaccess

Comment: @AndreiVlad you can put rules in the Apache config if you're worried about performance instead of .htaccess. But that is the only way you will get a **clean** URL without having to use index.php in the URL which doesn't look **Friendly** to me.

Comment: @HardikBhavsar I understand but it was tagged with .htaccess so I provided an easier and `IMO` better way if you truly want clean URL's.

Comment: @PanamaJack Agree Man , but he want that without .htaccess.

Comment: Finally i've used htaccess. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, my comment keeps growing...so I guess I'll just provide an answer...

1) This still requires server configuration.  In the case of Apache, I believe it's called MultiView.  This is what allows Apache to look up a directory when the first path /file.php/somepage is not found...if you don't have the right configuration, it will just give a 404 error even though file.php exists.  So, if your intention is to avoid the need for server configuration, it won't work.

2) What you are doing is dangerous:

```
$includeFile = basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['ajaxpage'].".php"));
```

All I have to do is know where some of your files are and I can potentially cause one of your PHP files to run...e.g. run your nightly cron every 5 minutes and overwhelm your server or some other page that might do some damage...you need some way of forcing only files with a certain name can be included...e.g.

```
$includeFile = basename(realpath($includeDir.$_GET['ajaxpage']."Controller.php"));
```

By forcing a suffix of Controller to the filename, you just have to make sure not to use the name Controller at the end of the file name for any file you don't want to be include-able.

3) There are so many MV* style frameworks out there...and there are so many security considerations, etc., that it is not always wise to create your own until you understand many or most of them.  Even if you don't like them, using those frameworks will also help you learn some best practices for creating your own.

4) Finally, what in the world is the reason to avoid using URL Rewriting.  URL Rewriting is the STANDARD for both Apache and Windows to create clean URLs.  There is a reason that "everybody's doing it."  If it's performance, your way will actually, probably, be slower because apache first has to look to see if the path exists, then go up a directory and see if that file exists, then go up another directory and see if that file exists until it hits a match...then open that file.

Comment: "Finally, what in the world is the reason to avoid using URL Rewriting." making applications server-agnostic - too many frameworks, even today, assume you run Apache. In fact, in the Arch "AUR" repositories you can't install PHP without Apache.

Comment: @toon81, I'm not sure server-agnostic is an argument in this case.  The OP's example is even more Apache specific (requiring MultiView) than URL rewriting.

Comment: I was responding to your question, your question is why one should avoid URL rewriting. The answer is that one might not want to make assumptions about the sort of server people use.